How is fault tolerance possible when external environment can become entangled with your qubits destroying any possible interference?
How is fault tolerance possible when external environment can become entangled with your qubits destroying any possible interference. How are these kind of errors corrected?

Hi, welcome to QC SE. It seems you have two very open-ended questions here, so you might need to add some clarification, but maybe this points you in the right direction: Fault tolerance is possible thanks to the threshold theorem. As for how the errors are corrected, this is done using quantum error correction.
